# basic 5 choice roulette game in python

Tags: python

new python guy here

so i am trying to make a basic roulette game with 5 choices for the player to choose from. i managed to get the script to run without errors, but the section under "win_loss" doesn't seem to be registering, or at least not the if/elif parts. i can only assume that i didn't identify something correctly at the top.

tho i would gladly accept a finished answer, guidance would probably help me lean more. 
either way, all help is welcome.

```
import random

red = (1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36)
black = (2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,19,20,22,24,26,28,29,31,33,35)
green = 0
even = (2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36)
odd = (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35)

def main():
    print('Red = 1')
    print('Black = 2')
    print('Green = 3')
    print('Odd = 4')
    print('Even = 5')
    print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
    player = int(input('Place your bet, 1-5: '))
    print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')

    roll()
    win_loss()

def roll():
    spin = random.randint(1,36)
    print('Landed on: ',spin)
    print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')

def win_loss():
    if (roll) == red:
        print('You won $.45')
    elif (roll) == black:
        print('You won $.45')
    elif (roll) == green:
        print('You won $5.00')
    elif (roll) == even:
        print('You won $.45')
    elif (roll) == odd:
        print('You won $.45')
    else:
        print('You lost')

main()
```

Comment: i noticed i indented def roll() too much when posting the question. please disregard that.

Comment: You know that (in addition to using a non-sense equality, you may be wanting to use the ``in`` to check that roll is an element of the set), as you coded the ``if ... elif`` block, it will never reach the even and odd comparisons? A number is either red, black or green, so it will never reach the ``even`` or ``odd`` comparisons because the if, for sure, has already triggered

Answer (score 2):

Your functions don't return anything and they don't accept parameters. To have your `win_loss()` function know what the result of the roll was you need to do somehting like this:

```
def roll():
    return random.randint(0,36)  # Pointed out by Lallen, you need to include 0
    # move the print statements outside the function

def win_loss(roll):  # note the parameter here
    if (roll) == red:
        print('You won $.45')
    elif (roll) == black:
        print('You won $.45')
    elif (roll) == green:
        print('You won $5.00')
    elif (roll) == even:
        print('You won $.45')
    elif (roll) == odd:
        print('You won $.45')
    else:
        print('You lost')
```

And in your script:

```
result = roll()
win_loss(result)
```

Read more about [functions and parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) here.

Also note that your Boolean operations will not work. You need to test if the result of the roll is `in` your tuples not equal to them. Something like this:

```
# Note the curly braces. As Marius suggested using sets here will make your program a little more efficient
red = {1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36}
black = {2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,19,20,22,24,26,28,29,31,33,35}
green = 0
even = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36}
odd = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35}

...

def win_loss(roll):  # note the parameter here
    if roll in red:  
        print('You won $.45')
```

This will work much better now as `1 in red` will be `True` while `1 == red` will be `False`.

You will also need to make sure the players bet was a winning/losing one:

```
def win_loss(roll, player):  # note the new player parameter here
        if roll in red and player == 1:  # note the comparison between the players input and the choices you laid out in the beginning.
            print('You won $.45')
```

That extra Boolean expression will make sure the roll was in `red` and that the player bet on red. This will have to be done for all the different checks.

These as well as the points listed in the comments are some things that will help you along. I would strongly suggest doing a bit more reading or perhaps some online tutorials as there are a lot of potential problems in your code.

Comment: Chance equalities to ``in`` because ``red``, ``black``, ``green``, ``even`` and ``odd`` are sets

Comment: And include the players bet as a parameter to win_loss, `def win_loss(roll, player): if player == 1 and roll in red:` etc.

Comment: to be able to roll green the spin should be `spin = random.randint(0,36)`